# Using selected dropdownlist value in query

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to insert data into a sql server temporary table based on a value picked from a dropdownlist. In my model I have 4 classes:

```
    public class Customer
    {
        [Key]
        public int CustID { get; set; }
        public string CustName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Sale> Sales { get; set; }
    }
}

     public class Product
    {

        [Key]
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Sale> Sales { get; set; }
    }
}

        public class Sale
    {
        [Key]
        public int RecordID { get; set; }
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public int CustID { get; set; }
        public int InvoiceNo { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    }

        public class TempTable
    {
        [Key]
        public int recordID { get; set; }
        public string CustName { get; set; }
        public string PoductName { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public int InvoiceNo { get; set; }

    }
```

In my SaleController I have the following action:

```
            public ActionResult OldInvoice(Sale sale)
        {
            ViewBag.InvoiceNo = new SelectList(db.Sales, "RecordID",   "InvoiceNo", sale.RecordID);
            return View();

        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult OldInvoice(TempTable t, int InvoiceNoToSearch = 0)
        {
            var query = (from s in db.Sales
                         join c in db.Customers on s.CustID equals c.CustID
                         join p in db.Products on s.ProductID equals p.ProductID
                         where s.InvoiceNo.Equals(s.InvoiceNo == InvoiceNoToSearch)
                         select new
                         {
                             s.InvoiceNo,
                             s.Quantity,
                             c.CustName,
                             p.ProductName,
                             p.Price
                         }).ToList();

            foreach (var temp in query)
            {
                t.CustName = temp.CustName;
                t.InvoiceNo = temp.InvoiceNo;
                t.PoductName = temp.ProductName;
                t.Price = temp.Price;
                t.Quantity = temp.Quantity;
                db.TempTables.Add(t);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("OldInvoice");
        }
```

and finally my view is:

```
    @model IEnumerable<UsingDropDownListValueInQuery.Models.Sale>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "OldInvoice";
}

<h2>OldInvoice</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

@Html.DropDownList("InvoiceNo")

   <p>
       <input type="submit" value="Save" />
   </p>
```

}

I get the following error:
Unable to cast the type 'System.Boolean' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

If I enter in the Where Statement an Existing InvoiceNo it does the job but not if I try to pick the value from the dropdownlist

Comment: Impossible to understand what your really trying to so here, other than to say almost everything your doing is incorrect. As far as you specific error goes, `(s.InvoiceNo == InvoiceNoToSearch)` evaluates to a `bool`, either `true` or `false`. In your case `InvoiceNoToSearch` will always be `0` because of all your other errors. so `where s.InvoiceNo.Equals(s.InvoiceNo == InvoiceNoToSearch)` evaluates to `where s.InvoiceNo.Equals(false)` and since `InvoiceNo` is `int` not `bool` you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you're never actually sending the value back. In your view, you've created a select named "InvoiceNo", but in your post action, you don't have any parameters that can accept that value. The closest and probably the one you intend to bind to is `InvoiceNoToSearch`, but if that's the variable you want to use, your view needs to match:

```
@Html.DropDownList("InvoiceNoToSearch")
```

Of course, that means your `SelectList` in `ViewBag` no longer binds automatically as the options for that select, but that can be fixed by just explicitly specifying it:

```
@Html.DropDownList("InvoiceNoToSearch", (SelectList)ViewBag.InvoiceNo)
```